# My iPad mini will not sent text messages. The keyboard doesn't even pop up.

Tags: ipad

I can't even get the keyboard to appear.   It's ALL the people in my address book.

My phone will send them, but not my iPad mini.  How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you restart it?

Comment: Try restarting the iPad. Did the iPad used to show the keyboard? What happened when it stopped working? Do you use a keyboard cover for the iPad?

Comment: Are you observing this only in the Messages app or is the keyboard not popping up anywhere you are trying to enter text? Generally on-screen keyboard doesn't appear when the device is paired to an external bluetooth keyboard. If that is the case, unpair the bluetooth keyboard and try again.